# help regarding ubuntu 14 lts installation on windows

Tags: system-installation

I am using Windows 7 Ultimate (32 bit). I downloaded Ubuntu 14 LTS through torrent. But the installation does not go through. I get the error "Can not download the metalink and therefore the ISO". I have tried this 3 times, and each times I get same error.

Kindly suggest me an installation method that does not require internet connection or solve this problem.

Comment: Download the installation ISO from the Ubuntu website, not a torrent. Burn to DVD or USB pen. Boot into the live media. Install.

Comment: Thanks. How to boot into live media?

Comment: Once you have burned the iso, lets say to a dvd, simply pop it into the drive and boot frpm it.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps and tell me which part of it doesn't work and where you can get upto.

1 Install Unetbootin to make bootable USB unetbootin.sourceforge.net

2 Choose the version of Linux, in this case Ubuntu, and the version of it you want. Choose wisely between 64 bit and 32 bit, but we recommend 64bit generally.

3 Wait for it to make it and of course remember t plugin your USB

4 Reboot your PC

5 Go into your BIOS, usually f12 or f2 or something like that....it should say somewhere :)

6 Go into Boot order in the menus

7 Move USB to the top of the boot order

8 Exit saving changes

9 Should come up with a menu and choose Try Ubuntu without installing , or you could install directly but I prefer to use the Try Ubuntu without installing

10 There should be a file saying Install Ubuntu and click on that

11 From there on, read the steps carefully and all should go well

Hope this helps and of course Good Luck! :)

It should say an option to not to install updates